# Plot a continuous variable discrete

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have this data:

```
samp

date_block_num  sales
            <dbl>  <dbl>
 1              0 131479
 2              1 128090
 3              2 147142
 4              3 107190
 5              4 106970
 6              5 125381
 7              6 116966
 8              7 125291
 9              8 133332
10              9 127541
# ... with 25 more rows
```

`date_block_num` represents a month. I want to plot the date in a time series fashion.

If I use this code, `date_block_num` will be plotted as a continuous variable (0, 10, 20, etc.) but it should be discrete (1,2,3, etc.).

```
  samp %>% 
  ggplot(aes(date_block_num, sales)) +
  geom_line()
```

[image]

If I use this:

```
  samp %>% 
  ggplot(aes(as.factor(date_block_num), sales)) +
  geom_line()
```

or

```
  samp %>% 
  ggplot(aes(date_block_num, sales)) +
  geom_line(aes(group = date_block num)
```

I get:

```
geom_path: Each group consists of only one observation. Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic?
```

Any Idea how to fix this?

```
dput(samp) 
structure(list(date_block_num = c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 
9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 
25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34), sales = c(131479, 128090, 
147142, 107190, 106970, 125381, 116966, 125291, 133332, 127541, 
130009, 183342, 116899, 109687, 115297, 96556, 97790, 97429, 
91280, 102721, 99208, 107422, 117845, 168755, 110971, 84198, 
82014, 77827, 72295, 64114, 63187, 66079, 72843, 71056, 0)), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -35L))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to specify the x-axis labels using scale_x_continuous.

```
samp %>% 
   ggplot(aes(date_block_num, sales)) +
   geom_line() +
   scale_x_continuous(breaks = samp $date_block_num)
```